# mounting multiple partitions from a disk image file

Tags: bash, mount

I'm trying to write a small bash script which shall mount all partitions from a given disk image file. I know that this works, because I did this already in the very past, but I can't remember anymore. Maybe I was using somehow `/dev/mapper` but I can't remember. I'm using for the *sizelimit* parameter the actual size of the partition and not the absolute sector end of the partition.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
#!/bin/bash

source=$1
destination=$2

if !(fdisk $source -l); then
    exit 1
fi

echo ""

partdata=$(fdisk $source -l|grep $source|tail -n +2)

offset=0
sizelimit=0

while [ "$partdata" != "" ]; do
    read -ra ARRAY <<< "$partdata"

    echo "ARRAY: ${ARRAY[0]} ${ARRAY[1]} ${ARRAY[2]} ${ARRAY[3]}" #echo for debugging

    mkdir $destination"/"${ARRAY[0]}
    ((offset=512*${ARRAY[1]}))
    ((sizelimit=512*${ARRAY[3]}))

    echo "#mount -v -o ro,loop,offset=$offset,sizelimit=$sizelimit -t auto $source $destination/${ARRAY[0]}" #echo for debugging

    mount -v -o ro,loop,offset=$offset,sizelimit=$sizelimit -t auto $source $destination"/"${ARRAY[0]}

    echo ""

    partdata=$(echo "$partdata"|tail -n +2)
done

exit 0
```

EDIT: translated error-message:

> mount: /mnt/raspi_qr_prototype_test_sample.img2: Wrong file system
> type, invalid options, the superblock of /dev/loop1 is corrupted,
> missing encoding page, or some other error.

Comment: `offset=$offset,sizelimit=$sizelimit` why don't you want `partprobe` or leave the kernel detecting what partitions there are? Check you scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: My image file has a partition table and several partitions. Using mount without offset/sizelimit won't work, at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a different approach that doesn't need to take some offset calculations. Let's first create a sample file with DOS partition table:

```
truncate -s 20M file.img
printf "%s\n" o n p 1 '' +10M n p 2 '' '' p w | fdisk ./file.img
```

then you can mount the whole image as a loop device:

```
loopf=$(sudo losetup --find --partscan --show ./file.img)
```

`--find` will make `losetup` find the first free loop device and output it, like `/dev/loop0`.

Then `--partscan` will work like `partprobe`, it will read the image and detect the partition and create appropriate files representing them with offset locations as in the partitioning table:

```
$ ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2
```

After that, you can use `p1` and `p2` as normal partitions, as you would normally:

```
for i in "$loopf"p*; do
    sudo mount "$i"  "somwheere/$(basename "$i")"
done
```

After you're done, `umount` all directories and disconnect loop device with:

```
sudo losetup -d "$loopf"
```

Comment: When using `sudo losetup "$loopf" ./file.img` I get a warning that the last sector isn't used. My image file has a total filesize of 4294967295 bytes. So the last sector has only a size of 511 bytes and not 512. May this be a problem?

Comment: Using `sudo partprobe "$loopf"` creates an error: (language translation of error) _Error: Partitions outside the hard disk are not possible!_

Comment: `May this be a problem?` Depends on the partition table - I would create it so that the last partition does not use the last file. `Error: Partitions outside the hard disk are not possible!` - seems like that's the case anyway.

Comment: It seems my image is corrupt. My sysadmin has set a policy for a max filesize. And this maxfile size is lower than the needed filesize for my image.

Comment: Well, it's just 512 bytes - if it's `ext4`, you may lower the size of partition by one sector, run `fsck` + `resize2fs` and remount and just have 512 bytes unused.

Comment: Nope, my image should be around 16gb but it's only 4gb. Thanks for your help anyway. I guess your proposed solution will work under normal conditions. At least I found the real error now :-)

Comment: `it's only 4gb` Sounds like FAT32 partition problem.